# Crash using failable initializer

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I'm getting a strange crash using a failable initializer in Swift. I pretty sure it's a bug in Swift, but figured I do a quick post to see if I'm missing something obvious.

I'm writing an app using CloudKit and added a new convenience initializer to CKRecord:

```
extension CKRecord {
    convenience init?(cloudInfo: NSData?) {
        guard let info = cloudInfo else { return nil }
        self.init(coder: NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: info))
    }
```

This just uses archived data I created using CKRecord's `encodeSystemFieldsWithCode:` method to create a `CKRecord` instance. I used to simply have a method in my class to do this same thing and it worked fine.

When I call this initializer like this:

```
    let record: CKRecord

    if let rec = CKRecord(cloudInfo: self.cloudInfo) {
        record = rec
    } else {
        record = CKRecord(recordType: "Item", recordID: CKRecordID(recordName: self.id))
    }
```

When I make that call, I get a crash. It doesn't matter if I pass in nil for `cloudInfo` or a value. When stepping through the code, the crash seems to happen between returning from the init call and getting back to the caller. For example, if I pass `nil` and step into the `guard` statement in the `init` that seems to work, but as soon as I step off of it, I crash.

I've tried getting rid of `guard` and going with a simple `if let` construct, but same outcome. And, I've also just returned `nil` from the `init` without any other code, and that also crashes.

I've done the usuals: cleaned the build folder, rebooted, etc.

BTW, by "crash" I mean I'm getting: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffc)` at the call site.

Does anyone have any ideas? Maybe it's something obvious that I'm missing.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the call stack also?

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev there is no real call stack, plug the code into a Playground and watch it crash.

Comment: I'm sure there is a call stack. Otherwise, where are `self.cloudInfo` and `self.id` coming from?

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev it does not matter, replace `self.cloudInfo` with `nil` and `self.id` with `"myCoolId"` - they do not matter.

Comment: Okay, I've understood. Thank you for pointing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to *The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1)* book,

> For classes, however, a failable initializer can trigger an initialization failure only after all stored properties introduced by that class have been set to an initial value and any initializer delegation has taken place.

Taken from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html).

You can't extend an existing class with stored properties, so the first requirement is met. But to meet the second requirement, you have to delegate your initialization process like in code below:

```
extension CKRecord {
    convenience init?(cloudInfo: NSData?) {
        guard let info = cloudInfo else {
            self.init(coder: NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: NSData()))
            return nil
        }
        self.init(coder: NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: info))
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does the following work: http://pastebin.com/NV3TwCjp? Secondly: why does the compiler not warn of even prevent this?

Comment: @luk2302 because there is no parent class. That means that there are no stored properties that should be also initialized.

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev: that's it! A simple RTFM on my part, but I appreciate the help. I do agree with luk2302 that I would expect better compiler warning support for this. Seems straightforward.

Comment: This is not a good idea to believe to the Swift's compiler, runtime, etc. It's still in stage of active development, and things will change again in 3.0 just in a few time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in Swift 3, there seems to be a bug and a regression from Swift 2: [returning nil from a failable intializer crash the runtime](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-704).